# Getting AttributeError: in Python Code 2

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm reading the book "Programming Collective Intelligence" Chapter 6, Document Filtering. I'm just trying to run the code given in the book. But I'm getting this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
cl.train('the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog','good')
AttributeError: classifier instance has no attribute 'train'
```

The code I'm using

```
import re
import math

def getwords(doc):
  splitter=re.compile('\\W*')
  print doc
  # Split the words by non-alpha characters
  words=[s.lower() for s in splitter.split(doc) 
          if len(s)>2 and len(s)<20]

  # Return the unique set of words only
  return dict([(w,1) for w in words])

class classifier:
  def __init__(self,getfeatures,filename=None):
    # Counts of feature/category combinations
    self.fc={}
    # Counts of documents in each category
    self.cc={}
    self.getfeatures=getfeatures

    # Increase the count of a feature/category pair
    def incf(self,f,cat):
      self.fc.setdefault(f,{})
      self.fc[f].setdefault(cat,0)
      self.fc[f][cat]+=1

    # Increase the count of a category
    def incc(self,cat):
      self.cc.setdefault(cat,0)
      self.cc[cat]+=1

    # The number of times a feature has appeared in a category
    def fcount(self,f,cat):
      if f in self.fc and cat in self.fc[f]:
        return float(self.fc[f][cat])
      return 0.0

    # The number of items in a category
    def catcount(self,cat):
      if cat in self.cc:
        return float(self.cc[cat])
     return 0

    # The total number of items
    def totalcount(self):
      return sum(self.cc.values())

    # The list of all categories
    def categories(self):
      return self.cc.keys()

    def train(self,item,cat):
      features=self.getfeatures(item)
      # Increment the count for every feature with this category
      for f in features:
        self.incf(f,cat)

      # Increment the count for this category
      self.incc(cat)
```

Everything is fine. I don't understand why I'm getting this error message.

Comment: Your whole indentation seems to be messed up. Are all those functions intentionally inside `def __init__`?

Comment: @user5061: they almost certainly are.

Comment: You need to clean up your indentation. Stick to only using spaces and use 4 spaces per level of indentation. Set your editor to expand tabs to spaces when you type, and replace any existing tabs with spaces. You indented your methods too far and they are part of the `__init__` method now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The book *Programming Collective Intelligence* in chapter 6 *Document Filtering* defines `train()` as a function of the class `classifier`**, so it should be defined at same indent level as the `__init__()` you defined. Same is true for all other methods you wrote inside the `__init__()`.

So, your final code becomes:

```
import re
import math

def getwords(doc):
    splitter=re.compile('\\W*')
    print doc
    # Split the words by non-alpha characters
    words=[s.lower() for s in splitter.split(doc) 
          if len(s)>2 and len(s)<20]

    # Return the unique set of words only
    return dict([(w,1) for w in words])

class classifier():
    def __init__(self,getfeatures,filename=None):
        # Counts of feature/category combinations
        self.fc={}
        # Counts of documents in each category
        self.cc={}
        self.getfeatures=getfeatures

    # Increase the count of a feature/category pair
    def incf(self,f,cat):
        self.fc.setdefault(f,{})
        self.fc[f].setdefault(cat,0)
        self.fc[f][cat]+=1

    # Increase the count of a category
    def incc(self,cat):
        self.cc.setdefault(cat,0)
        self.cc[cat]+=1

    # The number of times a feature has appeared in a category
    def fcount(self,f,cat):
        if f in self.fc and cat in self.fc[f]:
            return float(self.fc[f][cat])
        return 0.0

    # The number of items in a category
    def catcount(self,cat):
        if cat in self.cc:
            return float(self.cc[cat])
        return 0

    # The total number of items
    def totalcount(self):
        return sum(self.cc.values())

    # The list of all categories
    def categories(self):
        return self.cc.keys()

    def train(self,item,cat):
        features=self.getfeatures(item)
        # Increment the count for every feature with this category
        for f in features:
            self.incf(f,cat)

        # Increment the count for this category
        self.incc(cat)
```